# Why empty parquet files are created while writing into s3 using pyspark job?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I am reading a cassandra table from pyspark, and I am observing for very small data there are three files got written into s3 but out of those 3 , one file was empty parquet file. I am wondering how **empty file creation took place ?**
below are my steps in pyspark job:

1. read a table from cassandra
2. coalesce(15) on data read from cassandra
3. write into aws s3 bucket .

Comment: Are you saying you have tried to read the three files separately and one does not have any data?

Comment: exactly ! when i tried to read parquet files written in s3 , then out of three files one file did not have any data.